# Not able to locate tag in kernel git repository

Tags: git

I have created local linux kernel git repository from which I want to check out v2.6.35.11.
The problem is

> git tag

does not show v2.6.35.11 in the tag list. This is the list for 2.6.35 kernels from tag command :-

v2.6.35

v2.6.35-rc1

v2.6.35-rc2

v2.6.35-rc3

v2.6.35-rc4

v2.6.35-rc5

v2.6.35-rc6

How can I found Which one of these is closest to 2.6.35.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.6.x.y kernels are long-term supported kernels which are not part of Linus' git kernel repoistory.

You'll find the 2.6.35 long-term repository here:

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/longterm/linux-2.6.35.y.git
```

Answer (score 0):

The quad-versions of the kernel aren't tracked in Linus's kernel repository; you need to follow [Andi Kleen's git repository](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/longterm/linux-2.6.35.y.git;a=summary) to find 2.6.35.* kernel maintenance. Kernel.org hosts several [long-term maintenance kernel trees](http://kernel.org/).